# I have Child,Mother M:M Table.How to select Child with all common Mother their has?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, many-to-many

I have 3 table with Mother, Child, and Junction like this

Mother

[image]

Child (ChildName ZZZ Should Have 53 Code)

[image]

Junction

[image]

I want to use Mother (at least 2) as Where Condition to know what child their has in common
like

```
 Select CodeChild 
    From Junction
    Where CodeMother in ('02','03')
```

What I expect to result

[image]

Comment: `I want to use Mothers as Criteria to know what child their has in common like` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I mean 'use mothercode (more than 1) on 'where' 
to result ChildCode'

Comment: Don't edit your question to indicate that the problem has been solved. Write your own answer instead and accept it when time allows.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this

```
Select Junction.CodeChild, Child.ChildName From Junction
Inner Join Child On Junction.ChildCode = Child.CodeChild
Where Junction.CodeMother = CodeMother
```

Answer (score 0):

**As per OP Edit**
Solved but appreciate any better ways
Since Mother condition can have 1-4 the query depends on that

For Example

```
Select r.ChildName
From (Select j.CodeChild From Junct j Where j.CodeMother = 2)M1
inner join (Select j.CodeChild From Junct j Where j.CodeMother =    3)M2 On
M2.CodeChild = M1.CodeChild
//If More Mother Condition Just put inner join M3,M4 and So on Here
inner join Child r on M1.CodeChild = r.CodeChild
```